# sql for aggregating a window

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need to aggregate a window (in PostgreSQL):

I have this table "locationtimestamp":

```
seq | location     | timestamp
-------------------------------------
1   | home         | 2018-01-02 18:00
2   | home         | 2018-01-03 08:00
3   | work         | 2018-01-03 09:00
4   | work         | 2018-01-03 16:00
5   | home         | 2018-01-03 17:00
6   | elsewhere    | 2018-01-03 18:00
7   | elsewhere    | 2018-01-03 20:00
8   | home         | 2018-01-03 21:00
9   | home         | 2018-01-03 22:00
10  | home         | 2018-01-03 23:00
```

And I want this result:

```
location  | min_seq | max_seq | min_timestamp    | max_timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------
home      | 1       | 2       | 2018-01-02 18:00 | 2018-01-03 08:00
work      | 3       | 4       | 2018-01-03 09:00 | 2018-01-03 16:00
home      | 5       | 5       | 2018-01-03 17:00 | 2018-01-03 17:00
elsewhere | 6       | 7       | 2018-01-03 18:00 | 2018-01-03 20:00
home      | 8       | 10      | 2018-01-03 21:00 | 2018-01-03 23:00
```

I tried to achieve this using window functions, but that's results in 10  rows (the amount of rows in the table) instead of the desired aggregated 5.

My attempt (Not working) so far:

```
SELECT
   location,
   MIN(seq) OVER w min_seq,
   MAX(seq) OVER w max_seq,
   MIN("timestamp") OVER w min_timestamp,
   MAX("timestamp") OVER w max_timestamp
FROM locationtimestamp
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY seq ASC)
ORDER BY seq
```

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cc5cdf419d2b02f9d70754a6fb3c0de1

Comment: @RadimBača Thx! Please see my comment on Gordon Linoff's answer. Is this the only way? Or are all the gaps-and-islands issues solved in a similar way? ;-)

Comment: I believe that you can use also other window functions like `lag` or `lead`, however, this is the most elegant solution I have seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a difference of row numbers:

```
select location, min(seq), max(seq), min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by location order by timestamp) as seqnum_l
      from locationtimestamp l
     ) l
group by location, (seqnum - seqnum_l);
```

That is works is rather mysterious at first.  Stare at the results of a subquery so you can better understand.

Comment: Thx Gordon! That's a solution ;-) But 'fiddling' with row numbers is the only way to aggregate rows in side a window? I was hoping there is a more descriptive/functional way to do this...?

Comment: @frankhommers . . . There are other methods, but this is the simplest in your case.